# How do I read extra lines of a text file in addition to my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, file-io, datagridview, text-files

```
private void open(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // only works for opening the table
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();            
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileLabel.Text = openDialog.FileName;

        // Use File.ReadAllLines, it's easier
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openDialog.FileName);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var text = line.Split(',', '\n');
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(text);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

This is currently my code for opening and reading. So I also have the writing code (actually I wrote a text file already) and I want to add in a few more pieces of information somewhere on the form but not on the `dataGridView1`

Now in my previous version I had the following code added for reading the extra lines of a text file.

```
int k = 0;
while (k < lines.Length)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < twoDTextBox.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDTextBox.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            statsBonus[j, i].Text = lines[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

    // these lines I would like to add to read in my new file
    textBox1.Text = lines[k];
    k++;
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = lines[k];
    k++;
    checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(lines[k]);
    k++;
}
```

Before I used to use textboxes but later found out it wasn't really efficient and dynamic.

So now how do I add the bottom lines to my form after reading the DataGridView lines?

Comment: It might be just me, but this needs a tad more explanation as to what you are trying to do exactly..

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer So say my textfile contains the following items that came from the Forms Controls: all of dataGridView1, a line from a text box, a line from a check box text, etc. Now in my new code, it will only read the datagridview data. But I want to read the lines after that that will fill in the other Form Controls.

Comment: You use a delimiter so you can check which data is from where. Say, write all your data from control 1 in your new textfile. You then write a delimiting character or line of chars, like ***END***. You then write your data from control 2 and add another delimiting line ***END*** and so on?

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes it's a 2d array of text boxes. This was my old code though. Uhm no it's not dynamic so it was a 6 x 3 before. I want to try and do this with a datagrid.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer I don't really know how this is done :( I only know how to use delimiter by copying that code somewhere.